# Tent & Ziegler, Lemma 7.2.11

Tags: model-theory

I try to understand the proof of Lemma 7.2.11 in Tent&Ziegler book: "If $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is independet over A and $J<K$ are subsets of I, then $tp((a_k)_{k\in K}/A\cup\{a_j|j\in J\})$ does not divide over A."
Proof in the book says "We may assume that $K$ is finite" - it's clear. And the last sentence says, "The claim now follow from Proposition 7.1.6 by induction on $|K|$." - that is not clear at all, besause:

1. Proposition 7.1.6: If $tp(a/B)$ does not divide over $A\subset B$ and $tp(c/Ba)$ does not divide over $Aa$, then $tp(ac/B)$ does not divide over $A$.
2. If $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is independent over $A$, then in particular $tp(a_0/A)$ does not divide over $A$ and $tp(a_1/Aa_0)$ does not divide $A$.
3. Now, we want to show that $tp(a_0a_1/A)$ does not divide over $A$. But it's impossible to use Propositions 7.1.6, because it's not clear, that $tp(a_1/Aa_0)$ does not divide over $Aa_0$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that $\text{tp}(a_1/Aa_0)$ does not divide over $Aa_0$ is clear from the definition of dividing. No type in $S(B)$ divides over $B$, since any sequence of realizations of $\text{tp}(B/B)$ is constant.

What you're missing to do the general inductive step is that if a type over $C$ does not divide over $A$, then it also does not divide over $AB$, for any set $B$. This also follows directly from the definition of dividing, since any sequence of realizations of $\text{tp}(C/AB)$ is also a sequence of realizations of $\text{tp}(C/A)$.

So the hypothesis "$\text{tp}(c/Ba)$ does not divide over $Aa$" in Proposition 7.1.6 is *weaker* than "$\text{tp}(c/Ba)$ does not divide over $A$". In this application, the stronger hypothesis holds.

To do the inductive step, we want to show that $\text{tp}(a_0\dots a_n/A(a_j)_{j\in J})$ does not divide over $A$. By induction, we know that $\text{tp}(a_0\dots a_{n-1}/A(a_j)_{j\in J})$ does not divide over $A$. And by independence, $\text{tp}(a_n/A(a_j)_{j\in J}a_0\dots a_{n-1})$ does not divide over $A$, and hence does not divide over $Aa_0\dots a_{n-1}$. So by Proposition 7.1.6, $\text{tp}(a_0\dots a_n/A(a_j)_{j\in J})$ does not divide over $A$.

Comment: sorry to dredge up an old post, but I was a little confused by this lemma also. you say that, by induction, we know that $\operatorname{tp}(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}/A\cup\{a_j\}_{j\in J})$ does not divide over $A$, but this isn't clear to me – what about the case $J=\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$? this isn't covered by the induction hypothesis, and indeed for it to hold we'd need a hypothesis that $(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})$ is algebraic over $A$, right?

Comment: for example, suppose we're trying to show that $a_1\perp_A a_0$ implies that $\operatorname{tp}(a_0,a_1/A\cup\{a_0\})$ does not divide over $A$; the only induction hypothesis we can use here is that $\operatorname{tp}(a_0/A)$ does not divide over $A$, which is vacuous and not useful for proposition 7.1.6., so we have to prove it directly.

Comment: so suppose for contradiction that we have an $\mathcal{L}_A$ formula $\varphi(v,w,a_0)\in\operatorname{tp}(a_0,a_1/A\cup\{a_0\})$ that divides over $A$, we want to derive from it a formula in $\operatorname{tp}(a_1/A\cup\{a_0\})$ dividing over $A$. the obvious choice is $\varphi(v,a_0,a_0)$, but this doesn't work, since the witnesses of dividing won't carry over properly. of course, this line of argument isn't taking advantage of the full strength of the hypothesis $a_1\perp_A a_0$, but I'm not having any more luck showing forking than I am showing dividing

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Oh, this is just a notational confusion, I think (which is my fault - I used very confusing notation!). The $a_0\dots a_{n-1}$ are supposed to enumerate $K$, and we're doing induction on $|K|=n$. This is not supposed to indicate that they are the first $n$ elements of the independent sequence. In fact they won't be except in the trivial case because all the elements of $J$ come before them in the sequence (this is what is meant by $J<K$).

Comment: oh gosh, I completely misunderstood the statement of the lemma in the book; I thought the notation $J<K$ meant that $J$ is (any) proper subset of $K$, in the way that we use "$<$" to denote a proper subgroup or submodule, etc. lol I've been racking my brain about it all afternoon!! thank you for clearing it up... so just to make sure, the notation $J<K$ means that every element of $J$ is strictly smaller than every element of $K$?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Ah, yeah, that's how I understand it. It's a bit ambiguous, but I think that's the only interpretation that makes sense in context.